# Unexpected error, the message was : Unable to connect to the database server 'localhost' EZ Publish

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, ezpublish

Hi i am using EZ publish , when i try to access my site i am getting this error .

```
 Unexpected error, the message was : Unable to connect to the database server 'localhost'
    Error #0:  in /var/www/lib/ezdb/classes/ezpostgresqldb.php on line 125
```

in my

```
/var/www/settings/siteaccess/plain_site/site.ini.append.php
/var/www/settings/siteaccess/nor/site.ini.append.php
/var/www/settings/siteaccess/plain_site_admin/site.ini.append.php
```

i have defined

```
[DatabaseSettings]
DatabaseImplementation=ezpostgresql
Server=localhost
```

server as localhost ,

also my database user name and passwords are correct

also my site url is correct

```
[SiteSettings]
SiteName=test
SiteURL=xxxxxxx/index.php
```

also my database server is starts correctly

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql  restart
```

in my web browser it only gives the error

```
An unexpected error has occurred. Please contact the webmaster.
```

so

```
1.are there any log files  i should check ?
2.what are the possible reasons for this error , thank you very much
```

Comment: `connection string` & `log file`

Answer (score 1):

I have never used postgresql with eZ Publish myself but if you are sure that your settings are OK, try to replace `localhost` by `127.0.0.1`. Depending on the PHP library which is used, it can help.

If you are looking for logs, check `/path/to/ezp/var/log/*`. If this directory is empty, then please make sure that your webserver can write into `/path/to/ezp/var`.

Answer (score 0):

Check what username and password is being used (`lib/ezdb/classes/ezpostgresqldb.php`).
It may be that your in settings are not being read. Ensure that you have loaded your  siteaccess properly in your override site.ini (`settings/override/site.ini`). It sounds like you have your connection strings lined up in your siteaccess ini files, but your siteaccesses are not being loaded.

Comment: in lib/ezdb/classes/ezpostgresqldb.php i checked         $server = $this->Server;
        $port = $this->Port;
        $db = $this->DB;
        $user = $this->User;
        $password = $this->Password; from all fields i get correct data , but the port is not specifed by me, is it a problem , should i define a port ?

Comment: also in settings/override i don't have a site.ini file , i only have a site.ini.append.php ?? why is that